# InstallShield 2010 - 1603 Fatal Error [Windows Installer] (Windows 7 Only)

Tags: iis-7, windows-7, windows-installer, installshield

I created an MSI InstalScript Project where i deploy a web based (ASP.NET) precompiled project copying the files during installation in the \inetpub\wwwroot\projectnamefolder, creating an AppPool and the virtual dir of course in the IIS. The setup works great in windows
XP Pro (SP3 i used). But soon as i try in Windows 7 (tried Ultimate and Home Premium) i get
a -1603 Fatal Error during installation...Windows Installer Help (MSI.chm) or MSDN for more info....

Dying to fix this...

[Edit] I think error occurs when trying to create the Application in the IIS.

[FIXED] Enable 32 Bit Apllications needs to be true when creating Application Pools through InstallShield in a 64 bit OS!

Comment: I am having same issue in Windows seven and Win server 2008 R2, 
someone please update this if any solution is there..
I am really frustated!

Comment: It was my web config marked read only in IS.
Found answer here
https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?192076-Creating-virtual-directories-in-IIS-7-on-Vista

Comment: That is nice, although it's been many years since I have used Installshield, I can't really tell if this would work with my issue, please answer though and I will mark as correct answer. Also you should try http://wixtoolset.org/ it is a very powerful and free installer.

Answer (score 0):

No permission. See [this MS support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834484)
So you have write access to the directory but does the account have permissions to modify the IIS settings?

Comment: But i am administrator, and the UAC is disabled, i even tried giving Everyone permissions Allow all in inetpub folder...